# Is secure pptp not possible on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, ipsec, pptp

From [1], it was said that

> > 1) All users and providers of PPTP VPN solutions should immediately start migrating to a       different VPN protocol. PPTP traffic should be considered unencrypted.

So, besides OpenVPN (since user need to install additional program), what would be the recommended choice if we use Ubuntu?

[1] https://www.cloudcracker.com/blog/2012/07/29/cracking-ms-chap-v2/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [L2TP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol). Most operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux) and devices such as phones/tablets have a built-in L2TP VPN client.